# Read image dimensions: exif vs gd vs imagemagick?

Tags: php, image-processing, gd, exif, imagick

Processing already done by imagick.

But we have a bunch of files already processed and in one of method want to extract only their width/height.

As I understand, Imagick to getImageWidth reads whole file and also loads it inside it's internal structures.

I want to know -- is exif or gd has some more lightweight methods to get only widht/height of image.

// It's ok to trust to exif meta

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just did a benchmark on **127 PNG images**. It seems **GD is the fastest** among GD and Imagick. If you only want to use ImageMagick then load the file with `pingImage` first and retrieve width and height. This is the fastest in IM methods. But still 3 times slower than GD.

```
+------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| Script/Task name                   | Execution time in seconds |
+------------------------------------+---------------------------+
| GD                                 | 0.010726928710938         |
| IM Multiple Instance               | 1.9311830997467           |
| IM Single Instance                 | 2.0554959774017           |
| IM Single Instance identifyImage   | 1.4270191192627           |
| IM Single Instance pingImage       | 0.036259889602661         |
| imagedimension-exif-gd-imagick.php | 5.467                     |
+------------------------------------+---------------------------+
```

ImageMagic Multiple Instance means initializing different instance for different image

```
foreach($pngs as $png){
    $im = new Imagick($png);
    list($width, $height) =array($im->getimagewidth(), $im->getimageheight());
}
```

ImageMagic Single Instance means using a single iterate-able instance of Imagick

```
$images =  new \Imagick($pngs);
foreach($images as $im){
    list($width, $height) =array($im->getimagewidth(), $im->getimageheight());
}
```

ImageMagick Single Instance pingImage means getting dimension after loading it using `pingImage`

```
$im = new Imagick();
foreach($pngs as $png){
    $im->pingImage($png);
    list($width, $height) =array($im->getimagewidth(), $im->getimageheight());
}
```

ImageMagick Single Instance identifyImage means identifying image after loading it with `pingImage();`

```
$im = new Imagick();
foreach($pngs as $png){
    $im->pingImage($png);
    $im_info = $im->identifyImage();
    extract($im_info['geometry']);
    //echo $width. "x$height\n";
}
```

And finaly the GD,

```
foreach($pngs as $png) {
    list($width, $height) = getimagesize ($png);
}
```

---

**Note:** Exif extension can not get [image dimension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exif-read-data.php). This is written in PHP manual,

> ***Height*** and ***Width*** are computed the same way *getimagesize()* does so their values must not be part of any header returned. Also, ***html*** is a height/width text string to be used inside normal HTML.

Comment: So it's just calls getimagesize(..)? Could you add getimagesize in your benchmark? Nice to see GD is 200 times faster :) Btw, dont' you know how getimagesize(..) works internally?

Comment: Are you sure? Then what does mean this from manual? "Note: This function does not require the GD image library."

Comment: Anyway, as I see "Reads the EXIF headers from JPEG or TIFF". There is not png or gif. So gd wins. Thank you!

Comment: How about including http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.pingimage.php in your test @shiplu.mokadd.im ?

Comment: @Bonzo thanks for pointing that function. Its really fast. I have added that benchmark.

Comment: Could you add imagesx and imagesy in the benchmark ?. Code snippet : imagesx(imagecreatefrompng($png));imagesy(imagecreatefrompng($png))